# VSCode: Add newline between braces after pressing Enter

Tags: visual-studio-code, indentation

I want an indented newline after typing opening bracket and pressing Enter in VSCode.

Here's an example where | is the cursor:

Current behaviour-

```
function f() {
|}
```

Behaviour wanted-

```
function f() {
  |
}
```

The behaviour I want is the default one, but I don't know what happened and it doesn't work like that now. I couldn't find a solution to it, so I'm asking here. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally, I found the issue. In settings.json somehow I had this included.

```
"editor.language.brackets": [
    
]
```

But by default **it's not there**, or rather this is the default setting:

```
"editor.language.brackets": [
    ["[", "]"],
    ["(", ")"],
    ["{", "}"]
]
```

TLDR: Just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, but the proposed solution didn't work.

Turned out that in the same `settings.json`, there was a line

```
    "editor.autoIndent": "keep",
```

I just removed this line and this solved it.

Adding this answer in case someone has the same problem.